# No Bootable Device - BIOS/UEFI mess up

Tags: boot, uefi, windows-8

I've seen and read many threads on the matter, I've been at this for the past 10 hours. I'm new to Linux (2 months) and need some guidance. I bought the `Acer R14` which comes with Windows 8.1 and quickly proceeded to install Ubuntu 14 on it through `USB` image. Result:

```
No bootable device
```

I did the same install, the same day, with the same `USB` on an older laptop and it worked.

After some research I believe I did a `BIOS` install instead of `UEFI`.

I then installed Ubuntu 15 but it wouldn't load either.

I accessed firmware, confirmed it's on `UEFI`, disabled Secure Boot (couldn't find any setting for Fast Boot though), and tried to boot to no avail. I then did a Boot Repair Disk to switch my Ubuntu install from BIOS to UEFI, didn't help.

I reinstalled Ubuntu 15 with manual partitioning this time following this [Installation of Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) Desktop on UEFI Firmware Systems](http://www.tecmint.com/ubuntu-15-04-installation-on-uefi-firmware/) which also didn't help. Tried Boot Repair again - no good.

After all that, I read somewhere that I should enable Secure Boot, allow a trusted `UEFI` file, and select my `HDD`; this finally got me into Ubuntu through the purple GRUB screen. I downloaded and installed all the system updates, did a reboot... infinite Ubuntu splash loading screen. I've been on that screen for 45 minutes now.

I'm at a loss here. Please help me out.

**Edit 1:** After waiting for an hour, I did a forced reset, took me to the purple GRUB screen, selected Ubuntu, infinite splash loading screen again.

**Edit 2:** I tried to reboot again and this time it worked for no particular reason. I installed Chrome, checked there were no system updates, rebooted and now back at the infinite splash loading screen.

**Edit 3:** Recovery mode did't load after waiting 15 minutes.

Comment: In GRUB, hit `e` on the Ubuntu option. This will let you edit your boot options. Remove the `quiet splash` screen and boot. (There's a key to boot at this point, but I don't recall what it is. Fortunately, there's a message at the bottom of the screen that tells you what it is.) This changes the Ubuntu logo to a series of text-mode boot messages. With any luck, one will provide an obvious clue. Take a digital photo and post it for us to see if you need help interpreting it.

Comment: I did that and it took me 15 minutes to reach the 3rd photo.

First, it slowed down here and took more or less 3 minutes
http://i777.photobucket.com/albums/yy53/ayoubelie25/20150920_175503_HDR_zpsgnh0vqfj.jpg

That was the result after 3 minutes: Failed to start udev, starting file system check
http://i777.photobucket.com/albums/yy53/ayoubelie25/20150920_175642_HDR_zpsgc3oo1mu.jpg

That's the end of the check, after another 10 minutes I'm still on that screen with nowhere to go
http://i777.photobucket.com/albums/yy53/ayoubelie25/20150920_180558_HDR_zpsvum3qeoh.jpg

Comment: I didn't manage to snap a photo but before that 3 min job it says failed to reset device - referring to my hard drive

Comment: Alright before the 3 minute start job I mentioned above, this is what I get: http://i777.photobucket.com/albums/yy53/ayoubelie25/20150920_182335_HDR_zpsm4ahsgot.jpg
I tried again and it got me in this time!
I won't reboot cos I know it'll get stuck again.
Anything I can do from inside Ubuntu??

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12502060/ pasted from boot repair. This really means nothing to me, maybe someone knows better

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing serious kernel problems. Chances are you've got hardware that's not supported by the kernel you're trying to use. This problem can sometimes be overcome by using a more recent kernel, which in turn normally means a more recent version of Ubuntu. (Well, unless you've got the technical skill to compile your own kernel from scratch, but you wouldn't be posting this question if you had those skills.)

Along those lines, "Ubuntu 14" and "Ubuntu 15" are insufficiently precise. Ubuntu version numbers are based on the year *and month* of the release, with releases occurring in April (".04") and October (".10") of each year. Thus, there have been 14.04, 14.10, and 15.04 releases, with 15.10 due out in about a month (October 22). Every even-numbered year, the April release is a long-term support (LTS) release, with "point release" updates every few months. LTS versions are supported for five years, but non-LTS releases are supported for just nine months, IIRC. Thus, going with an LTS support is best if you don't want to upgrade every 6-12 months; but if you need support for bleeding-edge hardware, you may need to stick with a non-LTS release and plan to update to the next LTS version (which will be 16.04). Currently, the latest LTS release is 14.04.3. Thus, the versions with the most up-to-date kernels are 14.04.3 and 15.04; however, the 15.10 pre-release version (available [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-desktop-next/daily-live/current/)) has an even more current kernel. I recommend you try those versions. If none of them work, [file a bug report.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) Include screen shots like the ones you posted and complete make and model information on your computer.

If you need a working computer running Linux *now* but can't get any current Ubuntu release working, you might try an unrelated distribution -- Fedora, OpenSUSE, Arch, etc. (Some distributions, such as Mint, are actually derived from Ubuntu and so are almost certain to do no better than Ubuntu.) There's a modest chance that one of them will have a kernel that will work, just because they may have incorporated an updated or new driver first. If that doesn't work or is unacceptable to you, you'll have to return the computer to the store and buy a new one.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am on 15.04. You might be right about the hardware incompatibility. At this point, Ubuntu loads once out of 5-6 times and nothing I'm trying seems to help. And no, I can't build my own kernel :) I'll have a think about non Ubuntu distros. Thanks again.